# How can i find out the indices in blender 2.78

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Im trying to get the indices of my object. how can I get them. Also how can I export them into the obj file?
I exported into obj.

```
  v 1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000

v -1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000

v 1.000000 0.000000 1.000000

v -1.000000 0.000000 1.000000


vt 0.9562 0.0001

vt 0.0001 0.9999

vt 0.0001 0.0001

vt 0.9562 0.9999


vn 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000

f 2/1/1 3/2/1 1/3/1

f 2/1/1 4/4/1 3/2/1
```

how do I get the indices(triangles)